# Website with database of users reporting compatibility between macOS version and software versions

Tags: compatibility

A couple of years ago, when I wanted to install Adobe Creative Suite 5.5 under macOS 10.13, I found a website on which users could report whether or not a certain software version worked for them under a certain OS version. It was a huge database, listing many different applications, and very helpful. On it, many users reported using software that Apple or the software manufacturers claimed were not compatible. Unfortunately I cannot find the site again. If it is still online, does anyone know the URL to this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one such site - the quality of the records here, I'm not sure:

https://roaringapps.com